# How do I set up user quota for /var/www?

Tags: debian, partition, directory, quota

I want to add quota per user in my Apache2 webroot. My `/var/www` directory is not a partition. I've found tutorials on how to set up quota for partitions, but how do I set up `/etc/fstab` without moving the directory to another partition?

By the way: How many MB is a Block in `block-hardlimit`?

Answer (score 0):

Quotas allow you to restrict both the number of blocks that a given user may
write and the number of files (inodes) he can create.
When a user reaches the hard limit, the operation in question is prohibited. When
the soft limit is reached, the user can still proceed for a specified amount of time
(grace period), even exceeding the defined limit. After this grace period, the soft
limit turns into a hard limit.
edquota and setquota can set this.

Whenever possible, world writable directories should be moved to a partition separate from the operating system. Otherwise, depending on the system’s implementation, an adversary who is able to fill the entire file system could successfully mount a denial-of-service attack. For a system-wide temporary directory, a RAM disk could be used.